# Splitting lines read from somewhere into substrings using bash

Tags: string, bash, split

Having filenames like:

```
7933_20220313_093818_214713981_original.jpg  
7933_20220313_102102_214502218_original.jpg  
7933_20220313_102104_214502220_original.jpg
```

I want to split these using `read` or `readarray`. It works, to some extents, with readarray, but not with read:

```
readarray -t f < <( echo *.jpg )
for n in ${f[@]}; do
    readarray -d_ -t  p <<< "${n}"
    printf '"%s"  "%s"  "%s"  "%s"  "%s"\n' "${p[0]}" "${p[1]}" "${p[2]}" "${p[3]}" "${p[4]}"
done
```

and output is:

```
"7933"  "20220313"  "093818"  "214713981"  "original.jpg
"
"7933"  "20220313"  "102102"  "214502217"  "original.jpg
"
"7933"  "20220313"  "102102"  "214502218"  "original.jpg
"
```

`readarray` adds `\n` to the last array element. I did not find a way to get rid of it.

Using `read`:

```
readarray -t f < <( echo *.jpg )
for n in ${f[@]}; do
    read -d_ -r -a  p <<< "${n}"
    printf '"%s"  "%s"  "%s"  "%s"  "%s"\n' "${p[0]}" "${p[1]}" "${p[2]}" "${p[3]}" "${p[4]}"
done
```

gives:

```
"7933"  ""  ""  ""  ""
"7933"  ""  ""  ""  ""
"7933"  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

Not what I did expect after reading `read` assigning subsequent strings split by a given delimiter (option `-d_`) into an array named after option `-a`.

```
readarray -t f < <( echo *.jpg )
for n in ${f[@]}; do
    IFS='\n' read -d_ -a p <<< "${n}"
    printf '"%s"  "%s"  "%s"  "%s"  "%s"\n' "${p[0]}" "${p[1]}" "${p[2]}" "${p[3]}" "${p[4]}"
done
```

Does not really do better.

Any way to make `readarray` not read eol, `\n`, into the last element?
Why does `read` only read until it read to the first delimiter of the string not assigning further parts delimited by the same delimiter to subsequent array elements as described within bash manuals?

bash-version: `GNU bash, Version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is relevant. As glenn's answer says, you've flipped `IFS` and `-d`; the former is used to set how data is split into fields, the latter sets where the read operation stops entirely (as it determines what the _record_ delimiter is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readarray` (aka [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile)) is primarily used for reading *lines* into an array (the default). When you specify a delimiter, newline becomes a plain character, and the `-t` option no longer trims the newline.

`read` reads one line. If you change the line-terminator with `-d`, then that's where read stops. Use `IFS` to maniplulate the *field* terminator.

I'd implement your problem with this:

```sh
for f in *.jpg; do
    IFS=_ read -ra fields <<<"$f"
    # now do something with the variables, for example, inspect them
    declare -p f fields
done
```

With your filenames, this would output

```
declare -- f="7933_20220313_093818_214713981_original.jpg"
declare -a fields=([0]="7933" [1]="20220313" [2]="093818" [3]="214713981" [4]="original.jpg")
declare -- f="7933_20220313_102102_214502218_original.jpg"
declare -a fields=([0]="7933" [1]="20220313" [2]="102102" [3]="214502218" [4]="original.jpg")
declare -- f="7933_20220313_102104_214502220_original.jpg"
declare -a fields=([0]="7933" [1]="20220313" [2]="102104" [3]="214502220" [4]="original.jpg")
```